# prove that $f$ is continuous on $A$ if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$is open in $\Bbb R^n$ for every open subset $V$ of $\Bbb R^m$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity

Suppose that $A$ is open in $\Bbb R^n$ and $f$ is a function from $A$ to $\Bbb R^m$. Prove that $f$ is continuous on $A$ if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$is open in $\Bbb R^n$ for every open subset $V$ of $\Bbb R^m$.

How to show this theorem. Please show me explicitly? I find two answers but one of these are so complicated and another is not enough to do in the exam to take proper-point. So please help me. Thank you

Comment: I would clarify the link between $A$ and $V$; I would write that " $f$ contn. on $A$ iff $f^{-1}(V)\cap A$ is open in $\mathbb R^{n}$..." To move from the topological def. of continuity to the usual on on the metric space $\mathbb R^{n}$ I suggest you to consider the neighborhood definition of continuity in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open subsets of $A$ with the subspace topology are exact the sets $A \cap U$, where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. If $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $R^{n}$, then $f^{-1}(V) \cap A$ is open in $A$. But $f$ is defined from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, so the preimage of any set is contained in $A$, so $f^{-1}(V) \cap A = f^{-1}(V)$. Hence $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $A$ for any $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, which is the definition of $f$ being continuous.

For the other direction suppose that $f$ is continuous on $A$. Then $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $A$ for each $V \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. But $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(V) \cap A$, so $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ by the characterisation of open sets in $A$.

Comment: @B11b I realised I'd only explicitly written one direction, so I added the other.

Comment: In fact I didnt understand second direction. That is to say, be first pragraph in your solution.but now got it how to solve.:)